# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{1+(\tan x)^\sqrt2}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can we evaluate $$\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{1+(\tan x)^\sqrt2}\ dx$$ Can you keep this at Calculus 1 level please? Please include a full solution if possible. I tried this every way I knew and I couldn't get it.

Comment: I like the title. Are you asking whether or not you need help? :-)

Comment: Where did this integral come from?

Comment: That irrational power is a killer. Somehow I doubt a simple solution exists.

Comment: [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) spits out some three screenfulls of a "simpler" integral including niceties like $e^{\cos x}$...

Comment: You say in a comment below that the bounds on the integral from $0$ to $\pi$. Omitting critically important information from your statement of a problem in your question is often yields unnecessary goose chases and wastes of other's efforts, so it is a courtesy to others to not hide things from them.

Comment: @Ovi : I'll echo anon's point.  If what you really want is a DEFINITE integral then you MUST include the limits of integration in the question.  I'm surprised no one (including you) has edited the question.  Sometimes a definite integral can be evaluated while the correpsonding indefinited integral can't be done.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't have the book with me when I posted this question so I didn't remember the limits of integration. I also didn't think it would make a difference. Until now I thought that the way you do all definite integrals is you find the indefinite integral and plug in the limits of integration, so once I had the indefinite I could plug in the numbers myself. Sorry again for the confusion this made.

Comment: @Ovi : Quite often it is possible to evaluate a definite integral even when the antiderivative has no closed form.  You could have mentioned that there were limits of integration that you had forgotten, and provided some probable values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed this was a Putnam question. The $\sqrt{2}$ is pretty much irrelevant. Notice

$$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt2}}=\int_\pi^0\frac{d(\frac{\pi}{2}-u)}{1+(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-u))^{\sqrt2}}=\int_0^\pi\frac{du}{1+\cot(u)^{\sqrt2}}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt2}}=\frac{\cos(x)^{\sqrt2}}{\cos(x)^{\sqrt2}+\sin(x)^{\sqrt2}},\qquad\frac{1}{1+\cot(u)^{\sqrt2}}=\frac{\sin(u)^{\sqrt2}}{\sin(u)^{\sqrt2}+\cos(u)^{\sqrt2}}.$$

so

$$2I=\int_0^\pi\frac{dv}{1+\tan(v)^{\sqrt2}}+\int_0^\pi\frac{dv}{1+\cot(u)^{\sqrt2}}$$

$$=\int_0^\pi\left[\frac{\cos(v)^{\sqrt2}}{\cos(v)^{\sqrt2}+\sin(v)^{\sqrt2}}+\frac{\sin(v)^{\sqrt2}}{\sin(v)^{\sqrt2}+\cos(v)^{\sqrt2}}\right]dv=\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(v)^{\sqrt2}+\sin(v)^{\sqrt2}}{\cos(v)^{\sqrt2}+\sin(v)^{\sqrt2}}dv $$

which is $\int_0^\pi1dv=\pi$. Ultimately, this is a *symmetry* argument.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Putnam problem from years ago. There is no Calc I solution of which I'm aware. You need to put a parameter (new variable) in place of $\sqrt 2$ and then differentiate the resulting function of the parameter (this is usually called "differentiating under the integral sign"). Most students don't even learn this in Calc III!

Comment: Differentiation under the integral sign for indefinite integrals? O_o

Comment: Oops. My fault. The original Putnam problem was the integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$. The problem as stated here must be undoable.

Comment: I'm confused. if it is a definite integral from 0 to $\pi/2$, simple change of variable $x \to \frac{\pi}{2} - x$ is enough to get the answer $\pi/4$. Why do we need to use "differentiate under the integral sign" trick?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it was important to include the boundaries but in my book it is from 0 to pi/2. However, I am only in AP calculus AB (which is equivalent to calculus 1) and this is in the chapter about the integrals and derivatives of logarithmic and inverse trig functions

Comment: So can you show the steps to using this x->pi/2-x trick? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @Ovi, under $x \to \frac{\pi}{2} - x$, $\tan x \to \frac{1}{\tan x}$ and $\frac{1}{1 + (\tan x)^{\alpha}} \to \frac{(\tan x)^{\alpha}}{1 + (\tan x)^{\alpha}}$. So $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1 + (\tan x)^{\alpha}} dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{(\tan x)^{\alpha}}{1 + (\tan x)^{\alpha}} dx$$ Adding both sides and divide by two, you get $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac12 dx = \pi/4$.