# What are some Integration Techniques unrelated to the Antiderivative?

Tags: definite-integrals

Are there any definite integration techniques which I could learn (calc AB student)? I mean techniques which don't require you to find the anti derivative. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, certainly! Integration by parts, to start with.

Comment: Integration by parts involves finding the derivative. I am looking for ways to find definite integrals (some of which even wolframalpha can't find the anti derivative of), such as the integral of $dx/((1+tan(x))^(sqrt2) from 0 to pi/2.

Comment: Contour integration and differentiation under the integral sign are two well-loved techniques, but they might be a little difficult at the calc AB level. They also aren't guaranteed to give you a nice answer: sometimes there is no nice answer and you just have to numerically compute the integral.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yeah I looked up contour and diff. under the integral sign and it looked like I didn't have enough background to learn it. But I'm looking more for techniques such as this:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353414/evaluate-int-frac11-tan-x-sqrt2-dx  I really have no idea how Anon came up with that solution; is this a standard way of solving this kind of problem?

Comment: @Ovi: Still I wouldn't neglect it. Integration by parts is often necessary to "prepare" the integral for application of complex-analytic methods, which are by far the most powerful technique.

Comment: @Ovi: well, depends on what you mean by standard. Certainly you won't get a question that hard on the AP test. But symmetry is often a very useful tool. The simplest example is something like $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sin x}{1 + x^2}$; you don't need any fancy tricks to see that it's equal to $0$ because the integrand is odd.

Comment: @O.L. I already learned integration by parts, I guess next up is trig substitution.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for the tip, and I'm not trying to prepare for the AP exam; I already took it. I'm just learning on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the following apply mostly to definite integrals and not so much to indefinite integrals:

1) First off, geometry!  Some integrals are best done by noting they represent some well known geometric shape, such as the circle, or a cone.  Rather basic of course, but useful sometimes. e.g.

$$\int_a^b\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$

This is simply the arc length of a circle, though you might not have noticed immediately, and it can be solved by taking a part of the circumference and dividing appropriately.

2) Symmetry: As you have noticed, some integrals can be tackled with symmetry, especial integrals involving trig or some nasty polynomials and things of that nature.  e.g.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^n(x)}{\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)}\ dx$$

Notice that taking the integral backwards from $\pi/2$ to $0$, you get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^n(x)}{\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)}\ dx$$

And by adding them together,

$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)}{\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)}\ dx=\frac\pi2$$

This is best done by graphing the integrand and seeing if you can note anything special, or if the function looks like a puzzle piece to another integral, then proving what you think to be the case rigorously.

3) Differentiation under the integral sign (DUIS): It is what it sounds like.  You take some integral, and then take the derivative of it, though probably not in the way you'd expect.  e.g.

$$f(x)=\int_0^1\frac{t^x-1}{\ln(t)}\ dt$$

This converges for any $x\ge0$, thus, we may take the derivative with respect to $x$:

$$f'(x)=\int_0^1t^x\ dt=\frac1{1+x}$$

Integrating back:

$$f(x)=c+\ln(1+x)$$

And by setting $x=0$, we find $c=0$, thus

$$\int_0^1\frac{t^x-1}{\ln(t)}\ dt=\ln(1+x)$$

5) Polar coordinates.  e.g.

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\ dx$$

Notice then that

$$I^2=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\ dx\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}\ dy=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\ dx\ dy$$

This represents an integral over $\mathbb R^2$, but after converting to polar and letting $u=r^2$, this becomes

$$I^2=\int_0^{+\infty}2\pi re^{-r^2}\ d\theta\ dr=\int_0^{+\infty}\pi e^{-u}\ du=\pi$$

Noting that the $2\pi r$ comes from circumference.  We finally conclude that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\ dx=\sqrt\pi$$

6) There exist other more advanced [integral transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform), and I won't go into all of them, but the basic idea is simple: You apply a transformation on your integral to get a new integral, and then apply the inverse transform to recover your integral.  [Convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) are similarly useful here.

7) Complex analysis: Basically, this extends the idea of integration to the complex plane, and rather than integrating "along the real line from point a to point b" we may now integrate "along some path $\gamma$ in the complex plane from point a to point b".  Immediate advantages include being able to exploit more symmetries, taking advantage of real and imaginary parts, taking advantage of branch cuts, applying the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), and [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).  e.g.

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos(x)}\cos(x-\sin(x))\ dx$$

Notice this to be the real part of another integral:

$$I=\Re\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos(x)+i(x-\sin(x))}\ dx=\Re\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix}e^{1/e^{ix}}\ dx$$

By letting $z=e^{ix}$, and noting this becomes an integral along $|z|=1$ counterclockwise,

$$I=\Re\oint_{|z|=1}\frac1ie^{1/z}\ dz$$

And finally by the residue formula,

$$I=2\pi$$

8) Series expansions: Even though it doesn't always omit a solution, at least it provides a form good for numerical approximations.  Here is a good example:

$$I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac x{e^x-1}\ dx$$

We then note that $\frac x{e^x-1}=\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}$ and apply the geometric series to get

$$I=\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-x}+xe^{-2x}+xe^{-3x}+\dots\ dx$$

And by integrating term by term,

$$I=\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\dots$$

which is the well known Basel problem (or $\zeta(2)$ if you are more familiar with that) and gives us

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac x{e^x-1}\ dx=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

Comment: Great answer! I'm going to bed now but I'll read this in more detail tomorrow.